# Variable alignement with Cortex-M0 under GCC

Tags: c, gcc, linker, alignment, cortex-m

I'm trying to find a good way to align variables on a bondary of 32 bits or 16 bits with GCC.

I'm working on a Cortex-M0 that doesn't support the missaligned data acess. I have this problem when I use `-Os`. I use arm-none-eabi version 4.6.2. I have this small test case:

```
#include "stdint.h"

typedef struct Struct_HdrPrefix{
    uint8_t Prefix;
    uint16_t Type;
}__attribute((packed))Struct_HdrPrefix;

volatile Struct_HdrPrefix test;
volatile Struct_HdrPrefix test1;

int main(void)
{
    test.Type = 0;
    while(1)
        __asm("nop");
}

void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    while(1)
        __asm("nop");
}
```

When I compile this I get a non aligned variable test.

Here is the result in the map file:

```
COMMON         0x20000000        0x6 ./SRC/main.o
               0x20000000                test1
               0x20000003                test
```

So now I got to hardfault. If I add this to the vars:

```
volatile Struct_HdrPrefix test __attribute((aligned (4)));
volatile Struct_HdrPrefix test1 __attribute((aligned (4)));
```

This is working as expected since `test` is now aligned.

I can't use the align attribute on the struct since this struct could be part of another one packed too.

Is there a way to tell GCC or LD to align packed variables on a 32 bits boundary?

Regards

Comment: If you tell the compiler to pack a structure, you're telling it to ignore alignment concerns.  You can't really have it both ways.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind:

```
typedef struct Struct_HdrPrefix{
    uint8_t Prefix;
    uint8_t dummy; // for alignment
    uint16_t Type;
}__attribute((packed))Struct_HdrPrefix;
```

IF you want both packed structure and aligned fields, there is no other way. You have to align data manually. The only choice you have is where to insert `dummy` into (and how many to have).